# Is there something happening right now with mongoose ,mongo, express js or node? subtle updates?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, middleware

Suddenly my middlewares in express js  stop working even the ones  in server  that I did´t touch at all and were running the whole day normally, I tested previous versions of my node files locally which were working perfectly and  the same it´s happening to these files. Is there any subtle update or something, from mongoose, nodejs the browsers or something?

this is the middleware

```
import { ROLES } from "../models/Role.js"
import Users from "../models/Users.js"

export const checkDuplicateMail = async(req,res,next)=>{
const mail = await Users.findOne({email:req.body.mail})
if(mail) return res.status(400).json("Este correo ya está registrado")
next();
  }
export const checkDocument = async(req,res,next)=>{
const mail = await Users.findOne({idDocu:req.body.idDocu})
if(mail) return res.status(400).json("Este número de documento ya está 
registrado")
next();
}


export const checkPhone = async(req,res,next)=>{
const mail = await Users.findOne({tel:req.body.tel})
if(mail) return res.status(400).json("Este número de celular ya está 
registrado")
next();
 }

 export const checkRolesExist = (req,res, next)=>{
 if(req.body.roles){
    for(let i = 0; i<req.body.roles.length;i++){
        if(!ROLES.includes(req.body.roles[i])){

            return res.status(400).json({
                message: `${req.body.roles[i]} does not exist`
            })
        }

    }
  }
  next();

  }
```

This is the route

```
import {Router} from "express";

import * as authCtrl from '../controllers/auth.controller.js'
import { verifySignup } from "../middlewares/index.js";
const router = Router();

router.post('/signup'[verifySignup.checkDuplicateMail,verifySignup.checkDocument,verifySignup.checkPhone,verifySignup.checkRolesExist] ,authCtrl.signUp)
        router.post('/signin', authCtrl.signIn)
        router.post('/forgot-password', authCtrl.forgotPassword)
        router.post('/reset-password/:_id/:_token', authCtrl.resetPasswordPost)


  

     export default router;
```

Error

```
MongoError: E11000 duplicate key error collection: PFdb.users index: 
mail_1 dup key
```

Like the middleware doesn´t exist.

Comment: maybe, maybe not. how is your package.json defiend? do you have a package lock file? which midleware doesnt work? own code? show us please :)

Comment: It´s a middleware which check if something is already in the database when someone fills the registration form. I don´t have a package lock file.

Comment: you should be posting error or unexpected behavior that you are facing.

Comment: Missing comma after `router.post('/signup'`